# Size of a Byte[] array changes during execution in c#

Tags: c#, byte, arrays

I have created a class to manage serial ports which allows me to send ROM code to a virtual machine that is running on a robot.

This is the declaration:

```
public byte[] mensaje_a_enviar = new byte[4097];
```

Sometimes I send only 20 bytes or less but sometimes I have to send 4097 bytes in only one shot...

The strange problem is that this byte array resizes to something smaller (like 10 bytes) during runtime. 
This obviously throws me an overflow exception when I try to fill 100 bytes again for example...

I have only one instance of this class in my program.

Why could does it happen?

Comment: show us the code where you actually attempt the sending as well as the stack trace.

Comment: `The strange problem is that this byte array resizes to something smaller (like 10 bytes) during runtime.` No, never. You think so.

Comment: Something is calling "mensaje_a_enviar=" somewhere during your execution.  You probably will need to post more code in order to get help on this issue.

Comment: Write up a *small* complete program that demonstrates the problem. In doing so you will either produce a program that we can analyze, or you will find your bug.

Comment: I know it must not happen... I didn't want to post it as I thought that you will vote this down but this is happening to me... I see it in the debugger when it throws me the exception... How do I get the stack trace @Woot4Moo ? Sorry but I am studying electronic engineering and there are several things I don't know about VS...

Comment: An array cannot be resized after it's allocated so your problem is certainly somewhere else.

Comment: @leo2_uru If you are using Visual Studio right click on this variable and go to "Find All References" (Default: Ctrl+K, R in a C# environment) and look at everywhere that it is being used. Pay particular attention to where you see where it is being set. Figure out what calls the methods where it is being set. Something is setting it after it is created to a smaller array.

Comment: Could it be that I am filling with less bytes that it has what is causing the problem? It is not logical I guess. That is what i am doing before sending again the whole chunk of 4097 bytes. I am copying a public link to show you what is happening to me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25433633/charp_problem.JPG This is what I see in the debugger. Please tell me if I am missing something...

Comment: @leo2_uru Your problem isn't in the code in that image. The problem is that you're setting the array reference `mensaje_a_enviar` to a completely new array after you create it. This new array seems to have a Length of 9. You need to look at the places where you are setting `mensaje_a_enviar` to something, not where you are setting `mensaje_a_enviar[#]` to something.

Comment: Yes... I was doing this somewhere in my code... I thought the size of the vector wouldn't be changed. What a stupid mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Please mark an answer accepted, if you solved the problem yourself and no answer given was the correct answer please post your answer and mark your as accepted. That way your question will not keep popping to the front page with "No Accepted Answer" every few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code you have

```
mensaje_a_enviar = //Somthing
```

or

```
SomeFunction(ref mensaje_a_enviar)
```

Then inside `SomeFunction` you have something like the first line.

what those two examples are doing is replacing the array with a new array returned from whatever is on the right hand side of the equals sign. You should only be passing the array in as a parameter to a function without using a reference (`SomeFunction(mensaje_a_enviar)`) or be accessing the elements via the indexer (`mensaje_a_enviar[i]`).

Check your code and see where you are using one of the two pieces of code I had above.